# How to force sass variables to be used in specific scope?

Tags: angular, sass

I'm currently working on Angular 2 application. Simplified structure of project looks like:

```
|components/
|-- componentA/
    |-- componentA.ts
    |--componentA.html
    |--componentA.scss
|--componentB/
|...
|sass/
|--themes/
   |--themeX.scss
   |--themeY.scss
```

Each component is created in the same way:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'componentA',
    styles: [require('./componentA.scss')],
    template: require('./componentA.html'),
    ...
})
export class ComponentA {...}
```

I give user a possibility to change application theme and it's done by changing application main element class.
In each .scss file I do sth like below:

```
.theme-x {
@import '../../sass/themes/themeX';
h1 { color: $h1-color; }
...
}
.theme-y {
@import '../../sass/themes/themeY';
h1 { color: $h1-color; }
...
}
```

Theme scss files contains only variables.
It works, but I think that it could be written in more elegant way. The problem is that I have to write the same code twice and when I add new theme scss's, the code is going to be greater than the universe.
Any ideas?

Comment: could you pls share your code on a plunk